# Many to One Segue

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, uistoryboard

I have a ProductDescription ViewController that gets called from a ProductTable UITableView that I have placed in many ViewControllers.

It doesn't seem very efficient to ctrl+drag a segue for each tableView in the Storyboard, as I have approx 20 of them.

How does one do this programmatically?

Comment: ...why do you have twenty of them?

Comment: because they are embedded in other views who in turn are reused

Answer (score 2):

You have several options within UIKit to programmatically show a view controller without using a segue:

Push a view controller onto the navigation stack:

- `pushViewController:animated:`
- `showViewController:sender:`

Present a view controller modally:

- `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Answer (score 2):

The real answer here is to use storyboard references.  You shouldn't have the same thing in twenty different spots all trying to link to the same view controller to the point of asking this question.

So, let's create `Product.storyboard`, a storyboard which simply has two view controllers:

- `ProductTableViewController`
- `ProductDescriptionViewController`

And the appropriate segue between the two controllers.

Now, everywhere else in any of your other storyboards that want to use these controllers with this relationship, simply add a storyboard reference, add a container view controller, and add an embed segue between the container view and the appropriate view controller in the product storyboard.

You can accomplish this same effect even without using storyboard references.  Ultimately, the main point is to use container views and make embed segues from everywhere you need this relationship to the first of these two controllers, and then there's just a single relationship created between the two product view controllers.

Comment: This is all brilliant insight and is currently being implemented, however it is a TableView that is calling the segue, not a TableViewController. How could I make this work given a UITableView can not be a standalone item in a Storyboard?

Comment: Put your table view on a view controller?

Comment: Can I place a TableViewController within a ViewController?

Comment: You can use embed segues and child view controllers.